# android sql объединиее полей

Tags: android, sql

Имеется код:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 String sqlQuery = "select " +
           "tableJournals.id,"+
           "tablePacients.fio || tablePacients.birthday " +  
           "from tableJournals " +
           "left join tablePacients on tableJournals.idpacient=tablePacients.id ";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

по итогу хочу объединить два поля, что бы на выходе было как одно.
пробовал через:

```
"tablePacients.fio + tablePacients.birthday "
"tablePacients.fio || tablePacients.birthday "
"concat(tablePacients.fio,tablePacients.birthday) "
```

выходит ошибка

> 2022-08-11 11:40:38.925 21913-21913/com.example.arhivjournal E/SQLiteCursor: requesting column name with table name -- tablePacients.fio || tablePacients.birthday
> java.lang.Exception

Comment: Поля разных типов (строка и датавремя?) перед объединением надо привести к одному типу (строке). И вероятно, даже между ними добавить строчку "пробел".

Comment: добрый день, нет оба поля text

Comment: `||` очевидно неправильно. А вот какую ошибку выдает, если пишете `"tablePacients.fio + tablePacients.birthday "` ?

Comment: `tablePacients.birthday from tableJournals` - тут укажите вторую таблицу. `from tableJournals, tablePacients`

Answer (score 0):

Класс `Cursor` требует чтобы имена колонок не содержали точек. Соответственно нужно задать им псевдонимы:

```java
 SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 String sqlQuery = "select " +
           "tableJournals.id AS id,"+
           "tablePacients.fio || tablePacients.birthday AS pacient " +  
           "from tableJournals " +
           "left join tablePacients on tableJournals.idpacient=tablePacients.id ";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

Comment: ага большое спасибо, реально добавил псевдоним, все заработало, спасибос

Comment: @user514533 если все заработало то принимайте ответ